# Separating a pandas dataframe by columns on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I did search for an answer to my question, but I could not find a solution. 
The problem I am having is that I have a dataframe containing stock data (time stamp, open, high, low, close) of 45 stocks one next to each other and my original file looks like the below output which is just a snapshot of the data. Essentially on a row there is the time, open, high, low, close for every stock pasted one after the other.

```
Stock1                                    Stock2                                    Stock3
Time              Open  High  Low   Close Time              Open  High  Low   Close Time              Open  High  Low   Close
01/01/17 10:00:00 56.05 57.99 56.05 56.58 01/01/17 10:00:00 26.05 27.99 26.05 26.58 01/01/17 10:00:00 16.05 17.99 16.05 16.58
01/01/17 10:05:00 56.58 57.00 51.20 52.33 01/01/17 10:05:00 26.58 21.22 27.00 26.99 01/01/17 10:05:00 16.58 13.22 22.15 20.25
```

The stocks are all next to each other in the dataframe, which is causing me trouble. Ideally, I want to use python to separate my dataframe into different dataframes for each stock with the stock's name. I guess it can be accomplished with a for loop, however I have no idea how to specify that every 5 columns represent a different stock and need to be assigned to a new variable. So, I would like my output to be as below:

```
Stock1:
Time              Open  High  Low   Close
01/01/17 10:00:00 56.05 57.99 56.05 56.58 
01/01/17 10:05:00 56.58 57.00 51.20 52.33

Stock2:
Time              Open  High  Low   Close
01/01/17 10:00:00 26.05 27.99 26.05 26.58
01/01/17 10:05:00 26.58 21.22 27.00 26.99

Stock3:
Time              Open  High  Low   Close
01/01/17 10:00:00 16.05 17.99 16.05 16.58
01/01/17 10:05:00 16.58 13.22 22.15 20.25
```

I am new to python and I appreciate all your help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: *original file looks like the below output* ... this output looks like a result of a  `groupby` or `pivot_table`. Don't be shy, please share the code and even source data. We call that a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Parfait. I cannot add the original data as the columns misalign, thus I gave a snapshot of the data. As for the code, I do not have any as I am trying first to separate the data into different dataframes.